# need help on xpath or css : clicking common popup.gif for all table data element such as "One" , "two"

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

```
<div id="idp" class="att">
    <table class="attTab1" csp="0" cpad="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="atName">One</td>
                <td class="atValuePopup">
                    <img class="pi" src="img/shared/popup.gif"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="atName">Two</td>
                <td class="atValuePopup">
                    <img class="pi" src="img/shared/popup.gif"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**From comments**:

> I know table data element ahead of
>   time (such as, "one", "two", three" in
>   above snippet) and I want to click on
>   popup.gif image drop down menu to
>   verify the values in pop up list. So,
>   we need xpath or css which can find
>   popup.gif image based on table data
>   element (such as "one", two", "three")

Comment: so, I'm trying to come up with xpath which will allow me to click on popup.gif based on known table data element, such as "one", "two" in above snippet

Comment: @doneright: This absolute XPath expression selects those `img` elements: `/div/table/tbody/tr/td/img[@scr[substring(.,string-length()-9)='/popup.gif']]`. But if the question is clicking with selenium...

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for your response. I think I should have bit clear on my requirement. Here's my requirement is. I know table data element ahead of time(such as, "one", "two", three" in above snippet) and I want to click on popup.gif image drop down menu to verify the values in pop up list. So, we need xpath or css which can find popup.gif image based on table data element(such as "one", two", "three")

Comment: @doneright, it's been a year or two since I tried to use Selenium, but my recollection is that its "XPath" implementation is somewhat of a simplified version.

Comment: @doneright: your question is *not* done right.

Answer (score 1):

Use this absolute XPath expression:

```
/div/table/tbody/tr[td[@class='atName']='One']
                   /td/img[@src[substring(.,string-length()-9)='/popup.gif']]
```

Comment: @Alejandro : apparently selenium is failing to locate image using absolute xpath you provided

Comment: @doneright: I don't know what are the `div`'s ancestors like you do. You could try with a starting `//`...